# SQL Server not applying schema changes on replica enabled db. Replication type is transaction

Tags: sql-server

We have transactional replication enabled for SQL Server. The DBA says we can't make schema changes unless replica is disabled.

I recall using Oracle where changes can be made on the primary node and it's propagated.

Is this an accepted behavior in SQL Server, or are we missing something?

Comment: See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/replicate-schema-changes?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Replication supports replicating schema changes if this is configured (this is configurable per publicated article). If not configured, schema changes have to be performed manually, but they will still not require disabling replication unless the changes are incompatible with the data currently being inserted. Whether your DBA is right or wrong in this specific case is impossible to tell without more details, but *in general* schema changes do not require disabling replication.

Comment: It states
To disable replication of schema changes
On the Subscription Options page of the Publication Properties - <Publication> dialog box, set the value of the Replicate schema changes property to False.

Click OK.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.